# Assigning TextBox object reference to static event handler callback using Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I may have painted myself into a corner. I have a custom touch keyboard user control that uses static events to pass key presses to text boxes when they are in focus. I'm trying to make a dependency property for all text boxes to subscribe to my touch keyboard event handlers when they are in focus and unsubscribe when they lose focus.

My current problem is that the `PropertyChangedCallback`, `IsTouchKeyboardTargetChanged` never fires. I've read that this is because it is set in XAML and thus never "changes."

So far none of the other answers I have found quite apply to my pattern here. I'm not even sure that this is the right way to go about this, but it would be very convenient for me if this works. I'm following the example set my MahApps with their [TextBoxHelper](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro.Shared/Controls/Helper/TextBoxHelper.cs).

If anyone can help me resolve the `PropertyChangedCallback` issue, or if anyone has a better idea of how to accomplish subscribing/unsubscribing to static events when any and all text boxes fire focus events, I would be most grateful.

CS

```
public class TouchTextBoxHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTouchKeyboardTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsTouchKeyboardTarget", typeof(bool), typeof(TouchTextBoxHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, IsTouchKeyboardTargetChanged));


    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBox))]
    public static bool GetIsTouchKeyboardTargetEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsTouchKeyboardTargetProperty);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBox))]
    public static void SetIsTouchKeyboardTargetEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsTouchKeyboardTargetProperty, value);
    }

    private static void IsTouchKeyboardTargetChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = d as TextBox;
        if (null == tb)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The property 'IsTouchKeyboardTarget' may only be set on TextBox elements.");
        }

        if (e.OldValue != e.NewValue)
        {
            //tb.SetValue(SpellCheck.IsEnabledProperty, (bool)e.NewValue);
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                tb.GotFocus += TextBoxBaseGotFocus;
                tb.LostFocus += TextBoxBaseLostFocus;
            }
            else
            {
                tb.GotFocus -= TextBoxBaseGotFocus;
                tb.LostFocus -= TextBoxBaseLostFocus;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void TextBoxBaseGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TouchTextBoxEvents.tb = sender as TextBox;
        StaticEvents.OnShowTouchKeyboard(sender, e);
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardKeyTouch += TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardKeyTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch += TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch += TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch;
    }

    private static void TextBoxBaseLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StaticEvents.OnHideTouchKeyboard(sender, e);
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardKeyTouch -= TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardKeyTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch -= TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch -= TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch;
    }
}

public class TouchTextBoxEvents
{
    public static TextBox tb = null;
    public static void StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardKeyTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = tb.CaretIndex;
        string t = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(tb.CaretIndex, t);
        tb.CaretIndex = i + 1;
    }

    public static void StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = tb.CaretIndex;
        if (tb.CaretIndex == 0) return;
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(tb.CaretIndex - 1, 1);
        tb.CaretIndex = i - 1;
    }

    public static void StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = tb.CaretIndex;
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(tb.CaretIndex, " ");
        tb.CaretIndex = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Edit:

It turns out all I had to do was update my setter:

```
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBox))]
    public static void SetIsTouchKeyboardTargetEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsTouchKeyboardTargetProperty, value);
        TextBox tb = obj as TextBox;
        if (tb == null) return;
        if (value)
        {

            tb.GotFocus += TextBoxBaseGotFocus;
            tb.LostFocus += TextBoxBaseLostFocus;
        }
        else
        {
            tb.GotFocus -= TextBoxBaseGotFocus;
            tb.LostFocus -= TextBoxBaseLostFocus;
        }
    }
```

Edit2:

Putting the `PropertyChangedCallback` logic in the setter is a just bad. Fortunately, Clemens provided some great advice to use `RegisterAttached` instead of `Register`. This removed the need to derive from `DependencyObject` and cleared up the issue with the `PropertyChangedCallback` not firing.

Comment: If this is supposed to be an attached property, you should use `RegisterAttached` instead of `Register`. Note also that TouchTextBoxHelper does not need to be derived from DependencyObject.

Comment: Thank's for your advice! This fixed all my issues. I wish you would have put it in an answer so that I could give you rep and an all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attached property must be registered by calling `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached` instead of `Register`. There is also no need to derive the declaring class from DependencyObject:

```
public class TouchTextBoxHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTouchKeyboardTargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsTouchKeyboardTarget",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(TouchTextBoxHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, IsTouchKeyboardTargetChanged));

    ...
}
```